# Making a form in Angular with the option of adding new fields with the press of a button

Tags: angular, forms, rest, dynamic

I need to have two sections in my form with the following property:
We can add newer (text) fields (more details such as notes, or a phone number with a custom label, etc) to a contact on a smartphone by tapping on a '+' button.

I need to make a form in Angular with the same capability.

I'm new to the MEAN stack. If this was with JavaScript/PHP, I could generate more fields (with an `id` to identify it) inside a `div` element when a button was clicked.

Additionally, how can I retrieve the data in those dynamically generated text fields from my REST API?

Comment: please add some code which you tried

Comment: I found this:
(but I don't know how to retrieve data from these fields)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVNoYP

Comment: @Aravind it would be really great if you could help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
Used a model driven form template. Works perfectly:

[image]

Here's a tutorial which demonstrates this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

(sorry for answering this after 3 days, had to finish my projects)